# Get id value from $node->getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xml

I'm looping over a array like so:

```
   $objDOM->load("URL");
         foreach ($objDOM->getElementsByTagName('CRPublication') as $node) {
                $itemVacature = array (
                'naam' => $node->getElementsByTagName('titleInformation')->item(0)->nodeValue
         }
```

Now the loaded XML node has an dynamic id. Is it possible to get the value from the id where getElementsByTagName is titleInformation?

The xml node I need to get the id from looks like so:

```
<createdBy>
<CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
</createdBy>
<modifiedBy>
<CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
</modifiedBy>
<owner>
<CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
</owner>
```

As you can see I only get the id from this external company. I have to convert these id's to values that make sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is value of id attribute?

Comment: present an example of the xml please, since the id is dynamic is thexml element holding this information tagged somehow?

Comment: The id is dynamic, so for one total node id it can be 1, for the next one it might be 10. That is the information I need.

Comment: @Peter Darmis The element holding the id is always tagname titleInformation

Comment: The XML is not a valid document and does not match your source. Please add a small but complete example to your question. As a side note - check out `DOMXpath::evaluate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of loop on a loaded an XML object using `DOM Document` having parent,child and grand-child structure.

```
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Parent>
        <child>child 1</child>
        <child>child 2</child>
        <child>child 3</child>
        <subParent>
            <Grandchild>Grandchild 1</Grandchild>
            <Grandchild>Grandchild 2</Grandchild>
            <Grandchild>Grandchild 3</Grandchild>
        </subParent>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <child>child 4</child>
        <child>child 5</child>
        <child>child 6</child>
        <subParent>
            <createdBy>
                <CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
            </createdBy>
            <modifiedBy>
                <CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
            </modifiedBy>
            <owner>
                <CRUser id="122"></CRUser>
            </owner>
        </subParent>
    </Parent>
</root>';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $i=0;
    while(is_object($obj = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Parent")->item($i))) {
        foreach($obj->childNodes as $nodename) {
            if($nodename->nodeName=='subParent') {
                foreach($nodename->childNodes as $subNodes) {
                    if($subNodes->nodeName=='owner') {
                        if(!empty($subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id"))) {
                            echo $subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id")."\n";
                        }
                    }
                    if($subNodes->nodeName=='createdBy') {
                        if(!empty($subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id"))) {
                            echo $subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id")."\n";
                        }
                    }
                    if($subNodes->nodeName=='modifiedBy') {
                        if(!empty($subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id"))) {
                            echo $subNodes->childNodes['CRUser']->getAttribute("id")."\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(!empty($nodename->getAttribute("id"))) {
                    echo $nodename->getAttribute("id")."\n";
                }
            }
        }
    $i++;
    }
    /* Output
    122
    122
    122
    */
```

Check the output of the above example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc18b01c4567c151e1e21258ba474f91bb7bbf3c)

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your answer. I keep getting the following error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: @FrankW. Did you used the example as is? You should not, you have to change the tag names `Parent` `subParent` etc to the ones that should be used in your case. Most probably getAttribute is used in a node with attribute called id or without attribute at all.

Comment: I did not use the example one-on-one, but adjusted the tag names to the tagnames that I get supplied. Do I have to make use of simpleXML to make use of getAttribute? How come php tells me this is not a function? Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankW.  I have edited my answer in order to include the small XML part you provided in your question i hope it helps more.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for you answer again. Ill try it out as soon as I get home. Just have another question: Isn't it possible to direct select the node by tagname and then take the id instead of looping over each node? So something that looks like 'agency' => $node->getElementsByTagName('agency')->getAttribute('id')
Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankW. Since `$node->getElementsByTagName('agency')` may return not just one object or even if it was just one you would still have to access it like so  `$node->getElementsByTagName('agency')->item(0)->getAttribute('id')`

Comment: I thank you very much for your help! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute` assuming the schema to be same modified code. Try this.

```
$objDOM->load("URL");
foreach ($objDOM->getElementsByTagName('CRPublication') as $node) {
  $itemVacature = array (
                    'naam' => $node->getElementsByTagName('titleInformation')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'id' => $node->getElementsByTagName('titleInformation')->item(0)->getAttribute('id'),
                  );
}
```

Comment: since you don't have an xml schema in the question how can you know that is is `'id' => $node->getElementsByTagName('titleInformation')->getAttribute('id'),` and not `'id' => $node->getElementsByTagName('titleInformation')->item(0)->getAttribute('id'),`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in